# ios file corruption

Tags: xcode

Ok so some how 2 of my classes had ended up in a weird directory

> projectname>projectname.xcodeproj>

In my infinite wisdom I tried to transfer these to the proper directory were the rest of my classes are (projectname directory)

However now I cant compile due to it not being able to find certain files

what file can I edit to check to see where it's looking for these files?

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

[image]

in response to the first answer I have tried readding the files.  which has netted me some different errors.  Specifically that Cameleon-Prefix.pch, no matter how many times I re add it always shows red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix for this is to delete the files from Xcode, but in the confirmation dialog, choose to just release the references. Then add the files again (from the File menu Add Files… item).

If you want to see where Xcode expects to find the files, choose the file in the navigator pane on the left, and set up the right hand pane with this configuration.

[image]

And from there you can click on the detail disclosure buttons to see even more.

**Edited to add**

Make sure this is the same file pointed to in your build settings:

[image]

Do a similar search for `pch` to make sure the same thing goes with the pch file

Comment: thank you, this did help.  however now there is one last file it cant find.  projectName-info.plist   the file is there (not in red) under supporting files?

Comment: would you mind meeting me in ios chat room please?  its just that now its going through files, looking in the wrong directory, and when i add or readd files it puts them in the wrong directory (the same directory its looking at for files)  basically it added another <projectname> directory  so now its looking at and putting files into projectname>projectname> as opposed to just the root directory projectname